# How to simulate width of an text element before actual render with iTextSharp version 7

Tags: itext7

In one of my requirement, I want to get width of my text element even before it is rendered on the page.

In iText Version 5 the applied way was 
*(new Chunk("Test Text", SomeFont)).GetWidthPoint()*

But in version 7, I am unable to find anything matching this.
I have tried:

*(new Paragraph("Some Text")).GetWidth()*, but this returns null

Any help on this would be truly appreciable.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option for this is to query the font in question like this:

```
String text = ...;
float fontSize = ...;
PdfFont font = ...;
GlyphLine glyphLine = font.createGlyphLine(text);

int width = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < glyphLine.size(); i++)
{
    Glyph glyph = glyphLine.get(i);
    width += glyph.getWidth();
}

float userSpaceWidth = width * fontSize / 1000.0f;

System.out.printf("The width of '%s' is %s text space units.\n", text, width);
System.out.printf("For a font size %s, therefore, this is %s unscaled user space units.\n", fontSize, userSpaceWidth);
```

*([DetermineTextWidth.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext7/meta/DetermineTextWidth.java#L48))*